# Excel formulas needs to be clicked in order to get evaluated

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, xlwt

I've wrote an python program that basically reads excel formulas in form of `=FORMULA and write it into an output excel. Here is my code:

```
source=open_workbook('source.xls',formatting_info=True)

wb = copy(source)
ws = wb.get_sheet(0)

funWriter = open_workbook('template.xls')
VolProfile = funWriter.sheet_by_index(0)

    for row in range(VolProfile.nrows):
-   for col in range(VolProfile.ncols):
-        cellValue = VolProfile.cell(row,col).value
-        try:
-            if cellValue[0] == "`":
-                 cellValue = cellValue[2:]
-                 ws.write(row,col,Formula(cellValue))
-            else:
-                 pass
-         except:
-               pass
wb.save('Final.xls')
```

the code wrties the formula successsfully, however, the excel was unable to evaluate and generate a (#VALUE!) error unless I click onto the formula bar and press enter.

I tried to save it and press f9 and they all didnt work. 
Any idea on how to prevent me from clicking and pressing enter for 800 times??

Thanks!

Comment: (1) Your source code should be runnable as is so that can people can run it to try it out without having to guess missing imports and fix your indentation. (2) Please provide the contents of a SMALL `source.xls` and `template.xls` that reproduce the problem (3) `try: something ... except: pass` is an enormous code smell ... what errors are you sweeping under the carpet, and why?

Answer (score 1):

I'm NOT familiar with ANY language syntax except VBA, but to read and write FORMULA in cells one should use `Cell.Formula` property, not **value**.

Perhaps for Python it does not matter, but just the first thought.